# OpenSSL Crypt Functions Doesn't Work on PHP 7.4.5

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I just upgraded my PHP from 7.1.1 to 7.4.5. I was able to use openssl_*() crypt and decrypt functions on 7.1.1. Now, I can't use on 7.4.5. The error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   openssl_encrypt()

There are no libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files in PHP 7.4.5 folder. My Apache Server version is 2.4.25.

And extension=openssl is enable in php.ini.

May someone help about my first question on StackOverflow?

Comment: Did you enable extension_dir = "ext" as well ? (was disabled when I renamed the "php.ini-production" file to php.ini)

Comment: Yes, it is declared as right path to PHP Extensions directory. Already, other extensions work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem after 6 days. Here is solution for others:
After enable openssl in php.ini file and copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files into php7 directory, just included needed dll files into httpd.conf like that:

```
LoadFile "path\to\php7\libeay32.dll"
LoadFile "path\to\php7\ssleay32.dll"
LoadFile "path\to\php7\php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "path\to\php7\libpq.dll"
```

Comment: Note that latest php doesn't use `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. Instead you just need to load one: `LoadFile "${MY_PHP_ROOT}/libssh2.dll"`